# Why does my websocket handshake fail with unexpected response 200?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have seen this question several times, but I feel that my use case is not quite addressed, so I'm posting it below:

I get this error when trying to connect to my websocket:

`scripts.js:44 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

There's one small change that makes it fail versus succeed. See below:

Server.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// Failing:
const server = express().use(express.static('public'));
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening on PORT ${PORT}!`)
    });
///

// Working (no websocket connection issues):
///const server = express().use(express.static('public'))
//     .listen(PORT, () => {
//         console.log(`Example app listening on PORT ${PORT}!`)
//     });

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log(ws);
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received message: %s', message);
        wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(message);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

relevant: client code:

```
var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
var socket = new WebSocket(HOST); //this is the line where the connection is attempted.
```

Running on localhost, ngrok, or deployed to heroku seems to make no difference, unless I missed something...

I have tried various things from other posts but to no avail. They mention changing networking configurations (doesn't seem relevant to my use), or various ways to configuring express js, but they don't help. It's really just that small change in the above code. Is the websocket hitting the GET route?

Comment: One issue, at least with your localhost example, is `ws://localhost:3000/`.  That `:3000` is your development server port, and it will interfere with a web socket.  I'm not sure if you'd have the same issue when deployed elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user2740650. Do you know some resources that might explain why it interferes? I ask because the commented code works fine.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I forgot the websocket port (80) is the same as the http port (also 80) so I figured there might be some interference there.  When I saw that in your error message I figured it must be that.

Comment: Note that the `.listen` call may return a different server instance, so the working case (which chains `.listen`) might be returning a different server in your working case.  In your non-working case, they're not chained.